# Any way to import multiple (csv) files to an Access db

Tags: database, ms-access, csv, import

I have multiple csv files with the same scheme, and I want to import them in one step. A solution could be to use the "import wizard", but I can only import one file with it. Oh, and it would be the best to work in msaccess2003. THX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to start a dos-prompt, change to the directory where you have your files, and type:

```
type *.csv > allfiles.txt
```

If you do this often, you can create a [batch-file](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm) that you can double-click from your desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small program for importing see http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-09/03-qa-0922-access.html for java JDBC conector to msaccess  and since the import file is csv  you can do this in no time...

There are other importing options for other languages

Comment: and yes the option from Espo is easier if you need to do this only once or not automatically :)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is drive the import with a list of files, you don't need a batch file. You can get the list of files using Dir():

```
  Dim strCSVFileName As String 

  strCSVFileName = Dir("*.csv")
  Do Until strCSVFileName  = vbNullString
     [import strCSVFileName]
     strCSVFileName = Dir()
  Loop
```

Of course, this assumes you're doing the import from within Access, but given your tags, that's the logical inference of your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but it turned up when I searched for the issue.  Hopefully this code helps someone address the same challenge.  Builds / expands on the example David-W-Fenton offers, above.

I imported a file first, using the Wizard.  Imported into a table named "bestTranscripts" and saved the import template as "BestImport" -- then used those values in the TransferText command.

---

```
Function ImportFiles()

On Error Resume Next

Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim targetSet As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim sourceDirectoryName As String
Dim sourceFileName As String


sourceDirectoryName = "<path containing files>"

sourceFileName = Dir(sourceDirectoryName & "\*.txt")
Do Until sourceFileName = vbNullString
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "BestImport", "bestTranscripts", sourceFileName
    sourceFileName = Dir()

Loop


End Function
```